How can I exclude attachment content when searching emails in Outlook on the web?
When I search for a keyword in Outlook on the web, the search results include a plethora of emails that do not contain the keyword. At first blush, this makes no sense. My only guess is that the emails have attachments that do contain the keyword. Obviously, I want the search results to include only those emails that contain the keyword in their core non-attachment content, and to exclude those emails that contain the keyword only in their attachment content and not in their core content.
I've seen suggested solutions in similar discussions, but none of the suggestions work:

content:keyword
body:keyword
keyword NOT attachment:"keyword"

Each of these yield the same worthless search results, with tons of emails that do not contain the keyword in their core content. Does anyone know how to search only the core content of emails while ignoring any attachment content?
